# Re-ordering columns in Bootstrap 3 not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to re-order my columns when they compress down to a mobile phone.

For instance in the example below column A is on the left and column B is on the right for all screens apart from mobile (xs).

When the xs mobile breakpoint gets hit then A is on top and B is underneath.  The desired behaviour is that B should be on top and A should be on the bottom.  I made example simple but I also need to do this with more than 2 columns.

```css
.a{
  background-color: darkred;
  color: #fff;
}
.b{
  background: darkgrey;
}
.a,.b{
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 a">A</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 b">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSfiddle mirror: https://jsfiddle.net/hfd9jm5e/

I have tried every combination of col-xs-push/pull I can think of but it doesn't seem to work like the documentation describes.

How do I change the order of the rows on mobile?

Comment: Check out [column ordering](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) classes, a combo of those will do the trick. *Edit* or not :o

Comment: @KarlDawson Like I said in the question.  I have tried all combnations of col-xs-push/pull that I can think of but it does not work like the documentation says although the docs are extremely brief on it.

Comment: @MumfordJw solved it (I +10'd it) - work got in the way of me finishing my experimentation. `col-xs-12` basically honours source order at 100% width, so by reversing your A+B to B+A and using push/pull classes on the next breakpoint up you can then manipulate the visual layout.

Comment: @KarlDawson The logic hasn't clicked with me yet. Why does changing order on the next break point up help?  And why doesnt that actually change the order on that breakpoint? Trying it in my actual project and things are going all over the place so there is something I am not understanding.

Comment: Finally clicked.  It's mobile first so just wasn't thinking of the flow right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-6 b">B</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-4 a">A</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I changed your fiddle to the above and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: Thanks that does work but it confuses me.  using pull on sm makes me think it will change the order for sm not for xs.  I don't get why that effects xs.

Comment: I realise now its changing it from mobile first so the flow is up. That's why I need to change on next break point.